# Is this over-eager loader object an example of a Proxy Pattern implementation?

Tags: java, design-patterns, proxy-pattern

I have a Java system that consumes an API. A few days ago, we started facing the following problem: the remote API was receiving too many requests from my system. Back in the system's early days, it was not a major concern, but little by little the system's performance was getting worse and worse, since my data was growing and I made multiple requests for each entity. I noticed many of the network requests I made were not really necessary, since the data was not updated very frequently. So, I implemented a class that, when my system starts, makes an [over-eager loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299374/what-is-eager-loading) of all the remote API data. When I create/update an entity, I load it before any request is made. I treat deletion accordingly. And the remote API also notifies me when any change is made so I can stay updated even when this change is made outside my system.

What I really want to know is: is there any name for this practice? Any known design pattern 
? I must say I've done a little research and I think it is a [proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) but, again, I'm not very sure (in fact, most of the design patterns look very similar), and I'm not really that much into design patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call it a *Cache System* to what you implemented. Not sure if there is a dessign pattern for this though.

Also, the fact that the remote API notifies you when any change is made, might have been done using the *observer pattern*.

Comment: Yes, it is very likely a Cache System. I even started with a name like this. However, a _cache miss_ is something that can occurr in a usual cache, with a fallback method for retrieving data - but this does not happen in my system. It's more some kind of a mirror. Also, i don't think there's place for an Observer pattern here, since the API notifies me via a HTTP POST.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite a proxy pattern as the proxy pattern falls more under the heading of 'lazy loading'. From the description of the Proxy Pattern specified in
[Design Patterns (Group of Four Book):](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)

> One reason for controlling access to an object is to defer the full
> cost of its creation and initialization until we actually need to use
> it

I'm not sure what you'd call it other than over-eager loading