# DRF - browsable interface very slow with PrimaryKeyRelatedField

Tags: django, performance, user-interface, django-rest-framework, browsable

How can I make Django Rest Frameworks browsable UI fast with RelatedField?

I'm aware this has already been asked here: [Django REST Framework: slow browsable UI because of large related table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587726/django-rest-framework-slow-browsable-ui-because-of-large-related-table) but the answer is no longer valid for new versions of DRF

Including two PrimaryKeyRelatedFields gives me a 5s+ load time, removing them takes me back down to under .3

I've tried setting `html_cutoff=100` or even `html_cutoff=1`but it seems to make no difference to load times.

Any ideas? currently on DRF '3.3.2'

*Edit: tables involved have 12000 to 120 records - but it would be great to handle much larger amounts*

Comment: Might as well confirm it: is it still slow when you are retrieving it as JSON or does this only affect the browsable API?

Comment: Plain JSON is  fine. Sorry, I should have said that in the questions. See my "answer" below - it is a known issue, with a couple of PRs that could solve it in different ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite the answer I am looking for, but currently it looks like there is activity around this already on github - https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3329 with a little luck, one of those patches will get merged soon

Answer (score 2):

Since DRF version `3.4.4`, it's possible to limit number of relationships being displayed by using [selected fields cutoffs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#select-field-cutoffs).

From DRF documentations:

> When rendered in the browsable API relational fields will default to only displaying a maximum of 1000 selectable items. If more items are present then a disabled option with "More than 1000 items…" will be displayed.
>
> ...
>
> You can also control these globally using the settings HTML_SELECT_CUTOFF and HTML_SELECT_CUTOFF_TEXT.

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar or duplicate of this one [Django REST Framework: slow browsable UI because of large related table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587726/django-rest-framework-slow-browsable-ui-because-of-large-related-table/55379015#55379015#answer-55379015).

In essence it's **N+1** Problem and in context of Django it can be fixed by eager loading of data by calling `prefetch_related()` or `select_related()` on `QuerySet`. Check this [answare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587726/django-rest-framework-slow-browsable-ui-because-of-large-related-table/55379015#55379015)

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering this old question. I actually link to that question in my question. I've marked my answer as correct, and commented a link to the PR that fixed my issue, but upvoted your answer.