# STI has_many relationship in parent class inherited by sub classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

say I have the following STI models

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :childs, foreign_key: 'parent_id' # forgive the english for sake of simplicity

  #def childs
  #  Child.where(parent_id: id) # this works just fine BTW
  #end
end

class BadParent < Parent
end

class GoodParent < Parent
end
```

and the following Child class

```
class Child
  belongs_to :parent # parent_id lives on this
end
```

I dont care about setting the type on the Child so I don't care about creating a polymorphic association.

```
bad_parent = BadParent.create(name: 'Michael Jackson')
child = Child.create(name: 'Bobby', parent: bad_parent)
```

If I run

```
child.parent #=> <# BadParent > # AWESOME

bad_parent.childs #=> [] NO BUENO!!!

sql_statement = bad_parent.childs.to_sql #=> "SELECT `childs`.* FROM `childs` WHERE `childs`.`parent_id` = 1"

Child.find_by_sql(sql_statement) #=> [<# Child Object #>] BUENO!!!
```

Is there something I have to add to the association to make this work like `find_by_sql`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have the #childs method and also the has_many :childs association. Which one are you trying to use?

Comment: Well for starters you should use the proper plural form `children` to avoid errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per other comments, you shouldn't have both a method and association named the same as it is very unclear what will get executed - I'll assume for here on you will get rid of `def childs ...` Aside from that I think your issue is to do with caching i.e. rails will only hit the DB if it knows something has changed. In your example bad_parent doesn't know that new children have been added. You could either reload like:

```
bad_parent.reload
bad_parent.childs #> should show child object now
```

or force a call to the DB like:

```
bad_parent.childs(true)
```

Check out 3.1 Controlling Caching section of the rials guides for more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Yeah, weird. I am aware of rails caching db requests, but chalked it up to something with STI weirdness. It seems to work for me now with `#childs(true)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd do...

```
#app/models/person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  #columns id | type | parent_id | type_id | name | created_at | updated_at
end

#app/models/parent.rb
class Parent < Person
   belongs_to :type
   has_many :children, foreign_key: 'parent_id'
end

#app/models/child.rb
class Child < Parent
    belongs_to :parent
end

#app/models/type.rb
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | type
   #values good/bad (probably overkill to have DB for this)
   has_many :parents
end
```

This should allow you to call the following:

```
@parent = Parent.find params[:id]
@parent.children #-> collection of Person model with parent_id attribute for parent
```

In regards your specific issue - about [`eager loading`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299374/what-is-eager-loading) etc - I don't have masses of experience.

---

There *are* [hierarchy gems](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) which help this out.

We've used [`ClosureTree`](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) before - it creates a separate table which allows you to traverse hierarchies much easier. Another one is called [`ancestry`](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) which is pretty popular (easier to implement).

I'd recommend using the likes of `ancestry` in your "parent" model. I called the parent model `Parent` because I think it will give you much deeper scope to work with different types of data.

For example, your `Child` model is its own entirely, when it *should* be made up of the same data as the `Parent`.

Comment: Yeah, I like that alternative you suggest, but am wed to the current implementation (coded up already but will probably create an issue for it). +1 for suggesting `ancestry` and `closureTree` gems. I hadn't thought of those before now. Seems like my real issue is with AR db caching getting confused with STI. Thanks for your help!