# Performance of repeated getter calls vs. saving value in a local variable

Tags: java

Is one of the following options better than the other? What are the performance considerations?

```
class HelloWorld {
    String text = "Hello World";
    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }
}

HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();

// option A:
for (int i = 0; i < HUGE_NUMBER; i++) System.out.println(helloWorld.getText());

// option B:
String text = helloWorld.getText();
for (int i = 0; i < HUGE_NUMBER; i++) System.out.println(text);
```

I'm asking specifically about the case where (1) the getter function simply returns a property without performing additional calculations and (2) the property is never changed (there is no need to get a "current" version of it).

Answer (score 3):

The compiler might be smart enough to optimise option A into something similar to option B anyway, so here I assume the compiler does not optimise.

Option A involves many many calls to `getText` and many many accesses to the `text` field. Option B calls `getText` once and accesses the `text` variable many many times. Therefore, option A will take longer, since calling a method is not instantly. The method has to be added to the call stack, and when it returns, be popped from the stack.

But does this difference in speed *matter*? You'd have to check for yourself, using a profiler. *When in doubt, use a profiler.* If this is actually not causing the performance bottleneck, then changing from option A to B is not gonna help.

If you don't even have a performance problem right now, stop worrying about this. Wait until you do see your code running slowly, then check with a profiler.

Comment: All developers should make an attempt to profile their code even if there are no apparent problems. I'll wager that if you were to ask the meta question "how many times have you been surprised when you look at a profile of your code", then you'd get a lot of upvotes equating to "yeah, me too".

Comment: "If you don't even have a performance problem right now, stop worrying about this. Wait until you do see your code running slowly, then check with a profiler."

Completely disagree with this, as this encourages poor performing code especially if one is writing in languages where repeated getter calls are not being optimized by a compiler.

Answer (score -1):

In your this situation, I am willing to suggest that, you should think over all the angles here,

Option A - Is directly calling the function `getText()` while executing `System.out.println()`, some says this is a bad practice while writing so many lines unless you need to for a simple task. some says it halts the line quickly and do some other stuff and then come back here.

On the other hand Option B - It creates a new variable in the memory and storing the data which is almost consuming in terms of time and memory, but when you are printing the data it is super fast.

I can't really say which is well performed while people has different preferable scenarios on different level of tasks.

Instead I can help you with some info, which will help you while you go in the future : [Some Data Loading Concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1299381/7360506)

I hope it helps.